# Mongodb update triggers watch without changes occurring

Tags: mongodb, go

I am using `go` to create a websocket that watches changes to a mongodb collection

I have a function that is getting data and then running an update command on an interval.

```golang
        _, e := alertsCollection.UpdateOne(ctx, bson.M{"alert.fingerprint": alert.Fingerprint}, bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"alert": *alert}}, opt)
```

I also have a websocket watching the collection

```golang
    watch, err := alertsCollection.Watch(ctx, []bson.M{})
    logError(err)
    for watch.Next(ctx) {
        if e := watch.Decode(&alert); e != nil {
            log.Errorf("error decoding: %s", e)
        }
        resp, e := json.Marshal(alert)
        logError(e)
        logError(conn.WriteMessage(1, resp))
    }
```

This works as expected, except the watch is running even when no changes are run. Here is the result from a websocket listener.

```
Fri Aug 12 2022 10:40:26 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) <== {"_id":{"_data":"8262F6665A000000012B022C0100296E5A1004ECA7EFD21919485CB746D9A3AD11C27C46645F6964006462F666416A37B6C95FFEBD690004"},"clusterTime":{"T":1660315226,"I":1},"documentKey":{"_id":"62f666416a37b6c95ffebd69"},"ns":{"coll":"alerts","db":"atlas"},"operationType":"update","updateDescription":{"removedFields":[],"truncatedArrays":[],"updatedFields":{"alert":{"annotations":{"container":"","desc":"","title":"Host Ping Failed","tower":"","wiki":""},"endsat":"2022-08-12T10:44:21.281-04:00","fingerprint":"00930e3739c49713","labels":{"alertname":"Global_Host_Down","env":"prod","instance":"","job":"icmp","prom_team":"occ","replica":"1","service":"fire-alarm","severity":"critical","team":"route"},"updatedat":"2022-08-12T10:40:21.397-04:00"}}}}
Fri Aug 12 2022 10:40:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) <== {"_id":{"_data":"8262F66664000000012B022C0100296E5A1004ECA7EFD21919485CB746D9A3AD11C27C46645F6964006462F666416A37B6C95FFEBD690004"},"clusterTime":{"T":1660315236,"I":1},"documentKey":{"_id":"62f666416a37b6c95ffebd69"},"ns":{"coll":"alerts","db":"atlas"},"operationType":"update","updateDescription":{"removedFields":[],"truncatedArrays":[],"updatedFields":{"alert":{"annotations":{"container":"","desc":"","title":"Host Ping Failed","tower":"","wiki":""},"endsat":"2022-08-12T10:44:21.281-04:00","fingerprint":"00930e3739c49713","labels":{"alertname":"Global_Host_Down","env":"prod","instance":"","job":"icmp","prom_team":"occ","replica":"1","service":"fire-alarm","severity":"critical","team":"route"},"updatedat":"2022-08-12T10:40:21.397-04:00"}}}}
```

Even though the update command ran, no actual changes happened. Is there a way to only update if a chg in the fields occurs?

Comment: You'd need to compare it to the previous value. The watch will fire whenever there is an update, and you are issuing updates, you're just overwriting values with identical values.

Comment: What about "$or"? I tried using it, but got Unknown modifier: $or. Expected a valid update modifier or pipeline-style